# Error in wordpress database connection while hosting site

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I am trying to host a site which a built in wordpress. I have created the database on the server and also changed the credentials in the **wp-config** file. But it is giving me an error telling the `"Error establishing a database connection"`.

Here are the details:

```
<pre>
    /** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'abcwordpress');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'abcroot');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'abcd');
/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'http://abc.com/sample/wordpress/');
</pre>
```

`abcwordpress` is the database name of mysql, `abcroot` is the username of mysql db, 
`abcd` is the password and `url` as it is

What is wrong in the configuration ??

Comment: check 'DB_HOST' or try `define('DB_HOST', 'localhost')`

Comment: Check this define('DB_HOST', 'http://abc.com/sample/wordpress/'); try to use an IP address of the server you use, and check the username and  password, try to use it to login to the database itself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with DB_HOST it should be something like domain name or ip address

**eg: synux.sqlserverdomain.com**

You can check from your hosting provider to get mysql hosting server.

Many times it could be as simple as localhost

For more info : http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php